# JS file not loading on IE, works on Chrome in Joomla Seblod

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, seblod

I have added JS as a field on Joomla Seblod, which calls a JS file in my file system **my_profile.js** as follows-

```
jQuery.getScript("/components/com_msp/js/my_profile.js")
    .done(function(script, textStatus) {
    console.log('inside success in seblod');
    main();
}).fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    console.log('JS failed in seblod..');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqxhr));
    console.log( "Error:" + settings + ' : ' + exception );
});
```

On Chrome, the JS is called correctly and all the code works (I also get inside success in seblod message on the Inspect console), but on IE I get this on the console-

```
The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.
JS failed in seblod..
Error:parsererror : SyntaxError: Expected identifier
```

The code inside the files and everything is the same. Till yesterday I could see the changes on IE as well.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the Seblod developers to see if they have a fix for you?

Comment: It was being caused because of- Error:parsererror : SyntaxError: Expected identifier error above. Just some operators/identifiers that IE refuses to accept, and I had to find alternatives to do what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`parsererror : SyntaxError: Expected identifier` was actually causing issues with the JS code on IE. I had to do a line by line debug and finally found 2 instances in the code that was causing this-

1. I was using this to loop through an object- `for(const [serial, dates] of Object.entries(data)) {`. Had to replace this with a simpler **for...in** loop like- `for (var serial in data){ if (data.hasOwnProperty(serial)) {`
2. I'm using **sweetalert** in my script and a `.then((result) => {` inside it, and on some digging I found that IE doesn't take the arrow operators. So instead of that I used a `queue` on sweetalert actions and basically did the same steps but without the arrow operator.